# Segmentation fault: 11 c structures

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, structure

I have an array of structure records and a function `insert` to `insert or update` the records.

**The `insert` function take `list`(an array of records),`name` (book name),`author`, `year`,`copies` and size `n` of the `list`**

It **updates the record if it find's one otherwise inserts a new one**. here `n=7`

```
void insert(struct books *list,char name[],char author[],int year,int copies,int n)
{
    int i,found=0,empty;

    for(i=0;(i<n) && (found==0);i++)
    {
        // update works fine
        if( strcmp(name,list[i].name)==0 && strcmp(author,list[i].author)==0 )
        {
            list[i].copies=copies;
            list[i].year=year;
            printf("\n\n####################################################\n");
            printf("####\tRecord was successfully updated!\t####\n");
            printf("####################################################\n");
            found=1;
        }
        //get an empty record
        if(strcmp(list[i].author,"i")==0){empty=i;}
    }

    //insert gives segmentation error
    if(found==0)
    {
        strcpy(list[empty].name,name);
        strcpy(list[empty].author,author);
        list[empty].year=year;
        list[empty].copies=copies;

        printf("\n\n####################################################\n");
        printf("####\tRecord was successfully inserted!\t####\n");
        printf("####################################################\n");
    }
}
```

My `list` array is:

```
A
Ruby On Rails
2004
100
B
Inferno
1993
453
C
Harry Potter and the soccers stones
2012
150
D
Harry Potter and the soccers stone
2012
150
E
Learn Python Easy Way
1967
100
F
Ruby On Rails
2004
130
i
i
0
0
```

Why is it giving `Segmentation error: 11`?

Comment: "Sorcerer's" is misspelled.

Comment: "What is wrong with this code?" is not really an appropriate question.  Please ask something more specific - an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would help.

Comment: @BrianCain It's a dummy value.

Comment: How is `list` initialized and how is the struct `book` defined?

Comment: @BrianCain - I think you've hit on whats wrong.

Comment: @Steve `list` is initialized as `author=name="i" and year=copies=0`

Comment: SO is not a debugging service. Please run your code with a debugger, and provide feedback on what you think might me wrong.

Comment: `empty` isn't initialized

Comment: @Kninnug why does it needs to be initialized?

Comment: Because if it's not initialized, it can be any old random value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you need to initialize `empty`. Do

> empty=0;

**And really, SO is not a debugging service. So stop asking questions like this.**

Comment: They don't stop asking such questions until you stop answering such questions.